# Looking for a method to read an 8*8 matrix from a CSV file and store it

Tags: c, input, matrix

I am new to programming in C and looking for a method to read an 8*8 matrix from a CSV file and store it. Can anyone help?

Comment: How new, exactly, are you to C? In order to get your program to do things, you'll need to write *code*. What code have you written so far?

Comment: And where/how do you want to 'store' it?

Comment: well I have written to a csv file and now i want to read from it. I would like to store it into a matrix. I am trying to do the inverse discrete cosine transformation. any help from u would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) can be found here.

With [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html) you can use this grammar for parsing.

This is of course an overkill, but you will learn alot about a very nice parsing tool which can come handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have mentioned a 8 X 8 matrix. So as you know the dimension, you can statically allocate a 2d array. Otherwise you may have to parse the file once to find the n X m and then dynamically allocate memory accordingly (if you allocate memory dynamically, don't forget to free it!).

Your basic algorithm should be something similar to the following:

```
initialize _matrix_
initialize _row_ and _column_ to 0

open the file 
read a line
while the currently read line is not an empty line  
    split the line using comma as a delimiter
    initialize the _column_ to zero
    for all the elements (in the output of split)
        add the element to _matrix_[_row_][_column_]
        increment the _column_ by one
    increment the _row_ by one 
    read the next line
close the file
```

You should take care of the (error) conditions like the following:

- the csv file doesn't exist (open fails)

  - if matrix is dynamically allocated, then free it before exit!
- the csv file is empty (zero lines)
- the csv file contains lines that are not in the csv format (parse error)
- the contents of the file is of which type? char or int? what range? (data type error)
- what if there are more than 8 x 8 elements? ignore them?

Please use the standard-libraries/string-functions as above-mentioned by @Dave and try the algorithm that I've mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `strtok` `fgets` and `ato(f/i)` and `fopen` for starters. The general idea is that you read in the file, split by comma, then parse the substrings into the form you need them.